# Hibernate's `setFirstResult` not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class that returns all the entities in a query, limited by a max and a min:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <E> List<E> getAll(Class<E> klass, Integer startAt) {
    startAt = (startAt == null) ? 0 : startAt;
    int endAt = startAt + Constant.API_MAX_RESULTS;
    return (List<E>) HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(klass)
        .setFirstResult(startAt)
        .setMaxResults(endAt)
        .list();
}
```

Where `Constant.API_MAX_RESULTS` is `100`. So for example, if I want 100-199 genes, I will call:

```
getAll(Gene.class, 100);
```

If I print `startAt` and `endAt`, I correctly see `100` and `200`, but what I actually get returned is 0-199 inclusive genes.

When I configure Hibernate to show the SQL, I see this:

```
select this_.id as id8_0_, ... from gene this_ limit ?, ?
```

Should values be set on `limit`? Why isn't the lower bound working?

Comment: limit 100,200 will return you 200 records not 100. Maybe the confusion is coming from this fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate's `show_sql` shows the SQL with parameter placeholders, so it does not show the actual values. (It is logged at TRACE level though).

You problem is that you did not understand what `setMaxResults()` does, it sets the max. number of items fetched.

Answer (score 1):

.setMaxResults is the number of records at maximum that you want to return, so I believe you want setMaxResults of 100.